# Search different columns of table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to work a way where you can click a button and search by different columns in a table. I can figure out the buttons and to change the [0] to [1] to search different columns, but how would i make it more dynamic, using javascript. I only want to search by 1 column at a time, so only search by first name or only search by nationality etc...

it is a basic code, I did web programming 20 years ago and im trying to get back up to speed.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (filter) {
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase() == filter) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>All Information</h2>

  <div class="w3-bar">
    <button class="w3-button w3-black" style="width: 10%">#</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-teal" style="width: 10%">First Name</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-red" style="width: 10%">Last Name</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-yellow" style="width: 10%">Address</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-green" style="width: 10%">Age</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-blue" style="width: 10%">Date of Birth</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-purple" style="width: 10%">Nationality</button>
  </div>

  <input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search by ID Number..." title="Type in a number" type="text">


  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th class="w3-center" style="width: 2%;">#</th>
      <th style="text-align: left; width: 17%;">First Name</th>
      <th style="text-align: left; width: 17%;">Last Name</th>
      <th style="text-align: left; width: 16%;">Address</th>
      <th style="text-align: left; width: 16%;">Age</th>
      <th style="text-align: left; width: 16%;">Date of Birth</th>
      <th style="text-align: left; width: 16%;">Nationality</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-center">1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>Pearse Street</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>01/10/1977</td>
      <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-center">11</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Rosedale Avenue</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>17/04/1999</td>
      <td>American</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-center">114</td>
      <td>Tom</td>
      <td>Deane</td>
      <td>Greenwood Road</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>27/11/1980</td>
      <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-center">208</td>
      <td>Anna</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Rosedale Avenue</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>11/06/1999</td>
      <td>Scottish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-center">259</td>
      <td>Rachel</td>
      <td>Waters</td>
      <td>Station Road</td>
      <td>87</td>
      <td>11/02/1936</td>
      <td>Irish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-center">1</td>
      <td>George</td>
      <td>Taylor</td>
      <td>Beach Avenue</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>30/07/1971</td>
      <td>South African</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-center">1</td>
      <td>Neil</td>
      <td>Smyth</td>
      <td>Beach Road</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>15/12/2016</td>
      <td>Australian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-center">1</td>
      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>Smyth</td>
      <td>Beach Road</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>06/01/1993</td>
      <td>Australian</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const column = 3
const searchFor = 'GRE'
for (const cell of document.querySelectorAll(`#myTable tr td:nth-child(${column})`))
  if (cell.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(searchFor))
    cell.style.background = 'lightgreen'
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th class="w3-center" style="width: 2%;">#</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 17%;">First Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 17%;">Last Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 16%;">Address</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 16%;">Age</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 16%;">Date of Birth</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 16%;">Nationality</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="w3-center">1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Pearse Street</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>01/10/1977</td>
    <td>English</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="w3-center">11</td>
    <td>Tim</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>Rosedale Avenue</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>17/04/1999</td>
    <td>American</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="w3-center">114</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>Deane</td>
    <td>Greenwood Road</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>27/11/1980</td>
    <td>English</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="w3-center">208</td>
    <td>Anna</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>Rosedale Avenue</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>11/06/1999</td>
    <td>Scottish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="w3-center">259</td>
    <td>Rachel</td>
    <td>Waters</td>
    <td>Station Road</td>
    <td>87</td>
    <td>11/02/1936</td>
    <td>Irish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="w3-center">1</td>
    <td>George</td>
    <td>Taylor</td>
    <td>Beach Avenue</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>30/07/1971</td>
    <td>South African</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="w3-center">1</td>
    <td>Neil</td>
    <td>Smyth</td>
    <td>Beach Road</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>15/12/2016</td>
    <td>Australian</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="w3-center">1</td>
    <td>Sarah</td>
    <td>Smyth</td>
    <td>Beach Road</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>06/01/1993</td>
    <td>Australian</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like that ? (first version)

```js
const
  btSearch     = document.querySelector('#bt-search')  
, txt2search   = document.querySelector('#txt-2-search')
, searchResult = document.querySelector('#search-result')
, myTable      = document.querySelector('#my-table')
  ;
btSearch.disabled = true
  ;
myTable.onclick = ({target:TH}) =>
  {
  if (!TH.matches('th')) return;

  clearFounds();
  btSearch.disabled = true;
  
  if (TH.classList.toggle('selec'))
    {
    btSearch.disabled = false;
    myTable.querySelectorAll('th.selec')
      .forEach(th => th.classList.toggle('selec',th===TH))
    }
  }
btSearch.onclick=()=>
  {
  clearFounds();
  let txt     = txt2search.value.trim()
    , Rtxt    = new RegExp(txt, 'i')
    , nCol    = 1 + myTable.querySelector('th.selec').cellIndex
    , counter = 0
    ; 
  if (txt==='')
    {
    searchResult.textContent = 'nothing to search...';
    return;
    }
  myTable.querySelectorAll(`tr td:nth-child(${nCol})`).forEach(td =>  
    {
    if(Rtxt.test(td.textContent))
      {
      counter++;
      td.classList.add('found');
      }  
    })
  searchResult.textContent = (counter===0) ? 'no result' : `${counter} element(s) found`;
  }
function clearFounds()
  {
  searchResult.textContent = '.';
  myTable.querySelectorAll('td.found')
    .forEach(td => td.classList.remove('found'));
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  margin      : 1rem;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : lightslategrey;
  }
th { background: cadetblue;  padding: .3em .6em; cursor: pointer; }
td { background: whitesmoke; padding: .2em .5em; }
tr *:first-child { text-align: center; font-style: oblique; }
tr * { white-space: nowrap; }

th:not(.selec):hover { background: orange;     }
th.selec             { background: orangered   }
td.found             { background: aquamarine; }

caption {
  text-align : left;
  padding    : .4rem;
  font-size  : 1.2rem;
  background-color: #a0dbdd;
  }
#search-result {
  float     : right;
  font-size : .9rem;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <caption> 
    Find :
    <input type="text" id="txt-2-search" placeholder="select a column first...">
    <button id="bt-search"> do search </button>
    <span id="search-result">0</span>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Age</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Nationality</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Smith</td><td>Pearse Street</td><td>45</td><td>01/10/1977</td><td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td><td>Tim</td><td>Green</td><td>Rosedale Avenue</td><td>23</td><td>17/04/1999</td><td>American</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>114</td><td>Tom</td><td>Deane</td><td>Greenwood Road</td><td>42</td><td>27/11/1980</td><td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>208</td><td>Anna</td><td>Green</td><td>Rosedale Avenue</td><td>23</td><td>11/06/1999</td><td>Scottish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>259</td><td>Rachel</td><td>Waters</td><td>Station Road</td><td>87</td><td>11/02/1936</td><td>Irish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>George</td><td>Taylor</td><td>Beach Avenue</td><td>52</td><td>30/07/1971</td><td>South African</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>Neil</td><td>Smyth</td><td>Beach Road</td><td>6</td><td>15/12/2016</td><td>Australian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>Sarah</td><td>Smyth</td><td>Beach Road</td><td>30</td><td>06/01/1993</td><td>Australian</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> As the subject interested me...
>
> > And sorry, there may be a bit too many technical things here, but I've already spent a bit too many hours there, I'll come back to explain and comment. If any questions come up here in the meantime, I'll do my best to answer them.

```js
const
  txt2search    = document.querySelector('#txt-2-search')
, searchResult  = document.querySelector('#search-result')
, myTable       = document.querySelector('#my-table')
, tableHeads    = myTable.querySelectorAll('thead th')
, styleColHover = document.querySelector('#style-col-hover')
, mouseHoverTD  = ({target: TD}) =>
  {
  let ref = (!!TD && TD.matches('td')) ? TD.cellIndex +1 : -1;
  styleColHover.textContent = `td:nth-child(${ref}) { background: var(--col-hover);}`;
  };
myTable.tBodies[0].onmouseenter = mouseHoverTD;
myTable.tBodies[0].onmousemove  = mouseHoverTD;
myTable.tBodies[0].onmouseout =_=> mouseHoverTD({target:null});

txt2search.onkeyup = ({key}) =>
  {
  if (key==='Enter') searchProcess();
  }
myTable.onclick = ({target:colElm}) =>
  {
  if (!colElm.matches('th, td')) return;

  if (colElm.matches('td'))
    {
    tableHeads.forEach(th=>th.classList.remove('selec'));
    tableHeads[colElm.cellIndex].classList.add('selec');
    }
  else if (colElm.classList.toggle('selec'))
    {
    tableHeads.forEach(th=>th.classList.toggle('selec', th===colElm));
    }
  searchProcess();
  }
function clearSearch()
  {
  searchResult.textContent = '.';
  myTable.querySelectorAll('td.found').forEach(td => td.classList.remove('found'));
  }
function searchProcess()
  {
  let indxElm = myTable.querySelector('thead th.selec')?.cellIndex ?? 'x';

  clearSearch();

  if(isNaN(indxElm)) return;

  let txt     = txt2search.value.trim()
    , Regtxt  = new RegExp(txt, 'i')
    , counter = 0
    , query   = 'tr td:nth-child('+ ++indxElm +')'
    ; 
  if (txt==='')
    {
    searchResult.textContent = 'nothing to search...';
    return;
    }
  myTable.querySelectorAll(query).forEach(td =>  
    {
    if(Regtxt.test(td.textContent))
      {
      counter++;
      td.classList.add('found');
      }  
    })
  searchResult.textContent = 
    (counter===0) ? 'no result' : `${counter} element(s) found`;
  }
```

```css
:root {
  --col-hover : #eeafdb;
}
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  margin      : 1rem;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : lightslategrey;
  }
th { background: cadetblue;  padding: .3em .6em; }
td { background: whitesmoke; padding: .2em .5em; }
tr *:first-child { text-align: center; font-style: oblique; }
tr * { white-space: nowrap; cursor: pointer;  }

th:not(.selec):hover { background: orange;                }
th.selec             { background: orangered;             }
td.found             { background: aquamarine !important; }

caption {
  text-align : left;
  padding    : .4rem;
  font-size  : 1.2rem;
  background : #a0dbdd;
  }
#search-result {
  float     : right;
  font-size : .9rem;
  }
```

```html
<style id="style-col-hover"> td:nth-child(-1) { background : var(--col-hover);}</style>

<table id="my-table">
  <caption> 
    Find :
    <input type="text" id="txt-2-search" placeholder="select a column first...">
    <span id="search-result">0</span>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Age</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Nationality</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Smith</td><td>Pearse Street</td><td>45</td><td>01/10/1977</td><td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td><td>Tim</td><td>Green</td><td>Rosedale Avenue</td><td>23</td><td>17/04/1999</td><td>American</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>114</td><td>Tom</td><td>Deane</td><td>Greenwood Road</td><td>42</td><td>27/11/1980</td><td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>208</td><td>Anna</td><td>Green</td><td>Rosedale Avenue</td><td>23</td><td>11/06/1999</td><td>Scottish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>259</td><td>Rachel</td><td>Waters</td><td>Station Road</td><td>87</td><td>11/02/1936</td><td>Irish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>George</td><td>Taylor</td><td>Beach Avenue</td><td>52</td><td>30/07/1971</td><td>South African</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>Neil</td><td>Smyth</td><td>Beach Road</td><td>6</td><td>15/12/2016</td><td>Australian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>Sarah</td><td>Smyth</td><td>Beach Road</td><td>30</td><td>06/01/1993</td><td>Australian</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take Dar.

```
//Define a column to look in
// const column = 4

//Get the value from the input
// const searchFor = document.getElementById('myInput').value

//Grab all the cells for the column
columnCells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`#myTable tr td:nth-child(${column})`))

//Clear out previous matches
columnCells.forEach(cell=>cell.style.background = 'white')

//Filter the cells by the searchFor term
matchingCells = columnCells.filter(cell=>{
    return cell.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchFor.toLowerCase()) && searchFor != ""
})

//Color them
matchingCells.forEach(cell=>cell.style.background = 'yellow')
```